# Unity3d edit mode test cases hot to set platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, macros, preprocessor-directive, editmode

I have following code

```
#if UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
    public static MyPlugin Current = new MyPluginIOS();
#elif UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    public static MyPlugin Current = new MyPluginAndroid();
#else
    public static MyPlugin Current = new MyPluginEditor();
#endif
```

I am writing test case and want to select platform As UNITY_ANDROID how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to define the UNITY_ANDROID preprocessor directive.

```
#define UNITY_ADROID
```

From the Docs found [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives)

> #define lets you define a symbol. By using the symbol as the expression passed to the #if directive, the expression evaluates to true.

If you need to remove/undefine that preprocessor directive, you can use

```
#undef UNITY_ANDROID
```